# Are we able to hide the query parameter in flutter web while navigating through go_router?

Tags: flutter, flutter-go-router

Assume that I have to hide a few essential parameters which are sent through go_router's query params like - "

`GoRouter.of(context).pushNamed(route, queryParameters: { 'id': 'hhhhhh', 'key': 'yyyyy' });`

I don't want to let the user see the Id, is that possible in Flutter?

I tried the Uri.encodeQueryParameters() function which is present in `dart:convert` but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, You can't hide this but You can encrypt this and decrypt it from the other page so the query params should be something like data = "encrypted data" and then you decrypt it from the other page and for the user will see only the encrypted data

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

you can hide the data by using context.go instead of context.push. It may not be the best solution but it is a solution.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).